# Java HttpUrlConnection - 401 with authentication headers

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection

Chances are I'm doing something wrong, but using a Curl/Rest client I'm able to send a http request to a server using an Oauth2 generated token, here's the details:

```
url: https://blah.blah
Authorization: OAuth <oauth token>
Accept: application/blah (I'm hiding some of the details...)
```

This works fine using Curl/Rest and I'm getting back a JSON object as expected.  However, when doing this in Java, I'm getting a 401 every time.  I'm guessing I'm messing up appending the headers somehow, but I can't see how.

```
url = new URL(baseUrl+ reqUrl);
    System.out.println("Querying API with the following url:" + url.toString());

    httpReq = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpReq.addRequestProperty("Authorization: OAuth ", token.trim());
    httpReq.addRequestProperty("Accept", "application/blah...");
    httpReq.connect();
```

I'm guessing I'm getting the header set up wrong, but I can't see how.  Is there a better way to implement the headers to the http request?

Any input or advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Check this link https://developer.mastercard.com/portal/display/api/Java+OAuth+Sample+Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting **Authorization: *OAuth***  in curl while in code I see you are doing **Authorization:**  I see OAuth missing, I hope this is not an issue.

Comment: You're right, I was missing that.  I've just updated it, but the same thing is happening.  Thanks for noticing that though!

Answer (score 0):

Do not include "OAuth" in the key specification of either addRequestProperty() or setRequestProperty(). So this is incorrect:

```
httpReq.addRequestProperty("Authorization: OAuth ", token.trim());
```

Instead it should be a part of the value:

```
String header = "OAuth oauth_token=\"ConsumerKey%3D...\",oauth_consumer_key=\"...";
httpReq.setRequestProperty("Authorization", header);
```

The above should work.